# Как сделать так, чтобы не надо было писать папку которую надо создать в указанном input() пути?

Tags: python

Код:

```
import os

path = input("Path: ")

os.mkdir(path)
```

Как сделать так, чтобы не надо было писать папку, которую надо создать в указанном `input()` пути? То есть,  когда пользователь вводит путь, куда надо создать папку (history и common), не надо было указывать название этих папок.

Сейчас надо ввести вот так:

```
C:\Users\Zver\Desktop\Новая папка (2)\history
```

А надо вот так, но папка должна появиться:

```
C:\Users\Zver\Desktop\Новая папка (2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно добавить название необходимых папок в список и с помощью него создавать их по указанному пути:

```
import os

lst=['history' ,'common']
path = input("Path: ")
for i in lst:
    os.mkdir(path + i)
```

Обратите внимание, что путь должен иметь вид: Диск:\Ваш_путь\

Comment: не обратил, но потом всё же понял)

Answer (score 1):

Просто создайте две папки в пути, который вы указали в `input()`:

```
import os
path = input("Path: ")
history_path = f'{path}\history'
common_path = f'{path}\common'
os.mkdir(history_path)
os.mkdir(common_path)
```

Comment: Вы не поняли немного вопроса, я спрашивал как сделать так, чтобы не надо было писать 
диск\путь\НАЗВАНИЕ ПАПКИ
Так вот, надо чтобы НАЗВАНИЕ ПАПКИ не надо было писать, а папки просто сами создавались не указывая названия папки, а код сам делал эти папки

Comment: Изменил ответ, пришлось удалить одну строку

Answer (score 0):

```
import os.path

FOLDERS = 'history', 'common'

path = input("Path: ")
for folder in FOLDERS:
    full_path = os.path.join(path, folder)
    os.mkdir(full_path)
```

Применение функции `os.path.join()` вместо простого соединения имеет преимущество в том, что *не важно, если пользователь окончил путь обратным слешом или нет.*